Multiple nomad traefik instances in different namespaces
I'm building out a PoC Nomad environment for our developers to begin moving from full Linux VMs on VMware to containers.  Currently, our VMware hosts have multiple network interfaces to provide segmentation via firewalls to satisfy security compliance.  I have successfully overcome the hurdle of multi-homed Linux servers and Docker routing and can now start Nomad jobs on various network interfaces.
The issue I'm now trying to figure out is how to run traefik in this environment.  I attempted to run create Nomad namespaces for each network interface and have those instances running just fine within that namespace and on the proper network interface.  However, when I run a Nomad job for a web server container, within the same namespace and network interface, traefik does not discover it.  To make things a little more challenging, we are using Nomad's built-in service discovery for this.
Traefik is very new to me (as is Nomad) and I'm sure it's a simple matter of adding a tag for each traefik instance and web server container to point to the 'right' traefik instance.  Please let me know if that makes sense, what I can clarify, and how I can get this working.

Hi. create Nomad namespaces for each network interface I do not undersatnd. web server container to point to the 'right' traefik instance What is right? There is only one port 80, only only one proxy can listen on port 80. let me know if that makes sense I do not understand. what I can clarify Why namespaces are related to network interfaces? What does it mean for "traefik to discovery it"? What is the traefik configuration and what is your job specification? What does it mean to "point" as in "point server container"?

Nomad runs jobs. If a jobs service is healthy, nomad also has a database of services. Traefik periodically gets that list of services, and sources "dynamic configuration" taken from the tags of nomad services (plus a defaultRule). https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/nomad/  https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/nomad/ . That's it. Please show what specific traefik configuration, nomad job specification confguration, in particular service registration, you are using.
